# How do spellcheck algorithms optimize their search for suggested words?

Tags: algorithm, dictionary, spell-checking

From what I understand, spellcheck algorithms look for suggestions by checking the number of transformations (swapping letters, adding letters, removing letters, etc.) a given word would need to become one or more real words in a dictionary. I understand that they look at context as well, but let's leave that out of the equation for now.

Let's say that I want to see whether the word `overflw` would look like a word in the dictionary if it added 1 letter in the appropriate place. The only way I can see that being done is brute force: check whether each of

```
aoverflw
boverflw
coverflw
.
.
.
overflnw
overflow
overflpw
.
.
overflwy
overflwz
```

is a word in the dictionary.

Is there a more optimal way of doing that?

Comment: I highly recommend this http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html, very good read

Comment: You should look into the Porter-Stemmer algo [http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/porter/stemmer.html]

Comment: either something is optimal, or not. "more optimal" doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're working from the assumption that the spelling checker has a dictionary that can only tell you whether a word exists in the dictionary. But in most spell checkers the dictionary is implemented as some type of [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), often a [directed acyclic word graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_acyclic_finite_state_automaton) (DAWG). That's a much more versatile data structure than a simple dictionary with yes/no lookup capability.

Implementations vary, but conceptually you can view the search for a word in the dictionary as one in which it starts with the first character of the word and gets that node from the root of the DAWG. That node contains entries for all the following letters, etc. If you do that repetitively, you'll eventually end up with one of these possibilities:

1. You encounter a leaf node in the tree and you're at the end of the word. If this is true, you know the word exists in the dictionary.
2. You encounter a leaf node, but there are letters left in the word. Imagine if the word in the document were "fatx". You've reached the leaf node "t" in the tree, but you still have "x" left in your word.
3. You get to the end of the word, but you're not at a leaf node. For example, the word in the document is "overfl".
4. You're on a non-leaf node and you encounter a letter that is unrecognized. For example, the word is "overfdow". You're at the 'f' node in the tree, and the character 'd' is not in the list of letters that follow 'f'.

In the last three cases, you know what node you're at in the tree, and you know what letters (and, for that matter, what words) *could* be generated. For example, you have "overflw". The 'l' node in the tree says that the possible characters that follow 'l' are 'e' (overflew), 'o' (overflow, overflowing, etc.), and 'y' (overfly). If you want to do an exhaustive search of the possibilities in order to make suggestions, you don't have to try every letter in the alphabet. All you have to try are the letters that the dictionary knows follow "overfl". There's no need to check 'q' in this situation because we already know that it can't possibly match.

The basic idea is that the dictionary data structure (the trie) includes search behavior. Or, alternatively, the code that depends on the data structure has intimate knowledge of how the trie is implemented. That makes looking for suggestions much faster, although I wouldn't say that it's particularly easy.

Another thing you can do to speed searches is create another trie that has the words in reverse order. This is helpful if you want to find suggestions for words that are missing the first few characters. For example if somebody typed "elpful", you would want the suggestion of "helpful". You could search each first-level node, looking for "aelpful", "belpful", etc. But the reverse DAWG would start with 'l' and produce "lufple" ... then see that 'h' can follow, and suggest "helpful". This type of thing can be very useful when the 2nd or 3rd letter of a word is missing.

Basically, looking for suffixes is easy with a DAWG. Looking for prefixes is computationally expensive. But if you create a DAWG with the same word, only backwards, then prefix searches are just as effective as suffix searches.